# MySql Query build using Kohana's ORM

Tags: mysql, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3

I'm having a hard time to translate the following query into kohana's ORM.

So, if I do the following works fine:

```
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT id_book, MATCH(title, author, isbn) AGAINST (:str) AS score FROM tab_books WHERE status = 1 AND MATCH(title, author, isbn) AGAINST (:str) HAVING score > '.$score.' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100');
```

However, I need to use an specific class model. So far I have:

```
$books = new Model_Book();
$books = $books->where('status', '=', 1);
$books = $books->where(DB::expr('MATCH(`title`,`author`,`isbn`)'), 'AGAINST', DB::expr("(:str)"))->param(':str', $search_terms);
```

Which works fine, except for the fact that I'm unable to use the score value. I need the score because since I changed the table engine to InnoDB, the 2nd query is returning a lot of results.

ORM here: https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/ORM.php

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you don't use [query builder](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/Database_Query_Builder_Select), but [ORM object finding](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/ORM#having).
In first case you take result array on second array of objects.

Trust me, you don't want use list objects. (It's extremely slow)

```
$sq = DB::expr('MATCH(title, author, isbn) AGAINST (:str) AS score')
      ->param(":str", $search_terms);
$wq = DB::expr('MATCH(title, author, isbn)');
$query = DB::select('id_book', $sq)
  ->from('tab_books') // OR ->from($this->_table_name) for model method
    ->where('status','=',1) ->where($wq, 'AGAINST ', $search_terms)
  ->order_by('score', desc)->limit(100) //->offset(0)
  ->having('score', '>', $score);
$result = $query->execute()->as_array();
```

for query test:

```
die($query->compile(Database::instance()));
```

OT: Use

```
$books = ORM::factory('Book')->full_text($search_terms, $score);
```

instead `$books = new Model_Book();`